# EventBridge Pipes Target Input Transformer - Formatting lists/arrays

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am using EventBridge Pipes to connect DynamoDB Streams directly to EventBridge.  However, I am having difficulty transforming DynamoDB `list` attributes to my desired format using the Pipes Target Input Transformer.

## What I Want

When I insert an item into DynamoDB, I want to publish a `UserCreated` event to EventBridge without a Lambda Function.  I also want to *remove* the DynamoDB formatting from the event payload.

My DDB Stream event payload looks like this:

```
{
  "eventID": "c814968f8803051fa5700a2a0b9fe599",
  "eventName": "INSERT",
  "eventVersion": "1.1",
  "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
  "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
  "dynamodb": {
    "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1672592664,
    "Keys": {
      "sk": {
        "S": "PROFILE"
      },
      "pk": {
        "S": "USER#testuser"
      }
    },
    "NewImage": {
      "username": {
        "S": "testuser"
      },
      "roles": {
        "L": [{
          "S": "admin"
        },{
          "S": "otherrole"
        }]
      },
      "SequenceNumber": "3044600000000017324272463",
      "SizeBytes": 505,
      "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
    }
  }
}
```

I *want* my EventBridge event payload to look like this:

```
{
   data:{
     username: "testuser"
     roles: ["admin","otherrole"]
   },
   metadata:{
     eventType: "UserCreated"
   }
}
```

However, using the following Input Transformer

```
{
  "data":{
    "username": <$.dynamodb.NewImage.username.S>,
    "roles": <$.dynamodb.NewImage.roles.L>
  },
  "metadata":{
    "eventType":"UserCreated"
  }
}
```

I get the following output (notice the `roles` field still contains DDB formatting)

```
{
  "data": {
    "username": "testuser",
    "roles": [{
      "S": "admin"
    },{
      "S": "otherrole"
    }]
  },
  "metadata": {
    "eventType": "UserCreated"
  }
}
```

I do *not* want to publish DynamoDB formatted lists in my event payloads.

## What I've Tried

If I list out each list index manually, I'm able to get close to what I want

```
{
  "roles": [<$.dynamodb.NewImage.roles.L.0.S>,<$.dynamodb.NewImage.roles.L.1.S>]
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
{
  "roles": ["admin","otherrole"]
}
```

However, the size of this list is dynamic, so this approach will not work for me.

I've also used JSONPath.com to verify the following JSONPath expression is valid. However, the Pipes Input Transformer tells me this is an invalid syntax.

```
$.dynamodb.NewImage.roles[*][*].S
```

I may be able to use a Lambda Function to format the data to my liking in the Enrichment step of my Pipe.  However, introducing a Lambda Function would defeat the purpose of using Pipes for my use case.

Comment: I dont think so that what you are trying to achieve is possible because after all its the payload which is being transformed, if the original payload contains DDB formatting then your transformer will also have that unless you use static values which you have already tried

Comment: If you're correct, this seems like a pretty big limitation in the Input Transformer.  If one of the goals of EventBridge Pipes is to connect services without needing to write a Lambda function, I would expect the Input Transformer to be fairly robust.  Processing collections seems like a fairly common use case.

Comment: I think i am right, you can try aws repost where you can get support from aws team and if I am right I would be happy to post my comment as answer.

Comment: Thanks @JatinMehrotra, I will definitely report back once I get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to figure this out. I concluded that the feature was not supported, although I never had that confirmed from any official source or documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this with an express state machine for the enrichment. I wrote a blog about it [Solving the DynamoDB EventBridge Pipes Problem](https://jason.wadsworth.dev/solving-the-dynamodb-event-bridge-pipes-problem/). Below is the CDK code I used:

```
const userCreatedEnrichment = new StateMachine(this, 'UserCreatedEnrichment', {
    definition: new Map(this, 'UserCreatedEnrichmentMap', {}).iterator(
        new Pass(this, 'UserCreatedEnrichmentPass', {
            parameters: {
                'username.$': '$.dynamodb.NewImage.username.S',
                'roles.$': '$.dynamodb.NewImage.roles.L[*].S',
            },
        }),
    ),
    stateMachineType: StateMachineType.EXPRESS,
});

const pipeRole = new Role(this, 'PipeRole', {
    assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('pipes.amazonaws.com'),
    inlinePolicies: {
        sourcePolicy: new PolicyDocument({
            statements: [
                new PolicyStatement({
                    resources: [table.tableStreamArn],
                    actions: ['dynamodb:DescribeStream', 'dynamodb:GetRecords', 'dynamodb:GetShardIterator', 'dynamodb:ListStreams'],
                }),
            ],
        }),
        enrichmentPolicy: new PolicyDocument({
            statements: [
                new PolicyStatement({
                    resources: [userCreatedEnrichment.stateMachineArn],
                    actions: ['states:Start*'],
                }),
            ],
        }),
        targetPolicy: new PolicyDocument({
            statements: [
                new PolicyStatement({
                    resources: [defaultEventBus.eventBusArn],
                    actions: ['events:PutEvents'],
                }),
            ],
        }),
    },
});


new CfnPipe(this, 'UserCreatedPipe', {
    description: 'Sends UserCreated events',
    roleArn: pipeRole.roleArn,
    source: table.tableStreamArn,
    target: defaultEventBus.eventBusArn,
    sourceParameters: {
        dynamoDbStreamParameters: {
            startingPosition: 'LATEST',
            batchSize: 1,
        },
    },
    enrichment: userCreatedEnrichment.stateMachineArn,
    targetParameters: {
        eventBridgeEventBusParameters: {
            detailType: 'UserCreated',
            source: `MySource`,
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason!  Using a Step Function in the Pipe enrichment step hadn't occurred to me.  Feels kind of odd that Step Functions and Pipes have different capabilities in their JSON transformation.